# Qt : Remove border in Widgets windows (quickwidget example)

Tags: qt, widget, qml, frame, borderless

I'm starting a project using Qt, I've looked several examples and the best one for me is the [Qt Quick Widget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-quickwidgets-quickwidget-example.html). I'm looking to make disappear the border of the 2 small windows included in the main window.

I've used `Qt::FramelessWindowHint` but the only thing I've succeeded is to remove the border of the main window. Can someone please show me where I need to use this?

Comment: Are those two small windows in the main window inside a layout? If so, you can set the layout borders and inbetween spaces to 0.

Comment: They seem to be in a layout yeah but they are in seperate files (mainwindow.cpp), I'm beginning and don't know where to find the exact information to modify and where it is.. ? do you have the Qt example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
centralWidget ->addSubWindow(lcd, Qt::FramelessWindowHint);

...

centralWidget ->addSubWindow(m_quickWidget, Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
```

Comment: Hey,
If I do this I'm loosing the "widgets dragable" particularity of the SubWindowView. I Wish I could keep the subwindows but without any frame.

Comment: Do you want to keep the title bar and buttons close, minimize and maximize?

Comment: No I want to remove these ! No frame/border, only the inside. (I'm planning on using something like drag/drop after)

Comment: Wonderful :-) ! Now I can search my drag and drop problem ;-)